# Jenkins delay job delay for certain time between the Job A and B

Tags: jenkins

I don't understand what exactly `period` is doing. When trying to use it nothing happens.

I have a build job which generates a binary and down the line two downstream projects that are called Job A and Job B and I want to have a delay between A & B - Job B needs to start 10 minutes after Job A completes.

Any condition to trigger parameterized build or build after other projects?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no option to set delay for a downstream job in post build actions.

Alternatively, you can achieve this by adding `sleep 600`(Shell) at the end of your build step of job A.

Comment: Thanks Vivek...
can you give me like small example in post build actions included 2 projects
Project A - Testing
Project B - Validation 
I want to add the delay thing fro validation (project B) How can i do that tell me the syntax to do

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by vivekyad4v should work. Bear in mind that he said that action should be added in the build section.

If you don't want/can't use Shell, you can simulate the wait by executing a **Windows batch command**. It's also located in the build step section, not the post-build.

For example:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 30
```

This command would ping localhost (127.0.0.1) 30 times, approximately 1 ping per second, accounting to 30 seconds in total.

For a full set of options ping can provide just call `ping` locally in your cmd and check out what you need. You can run the example command locally as well, and play around with it before injecting it to Jenkins .

---

So, if I understood the organization of your jobs correctly, you would want:

1. Run the job which builds the binaries
2. Run the job A "Testing", and all the necessary post-build actions
3. Run the job B "Validation", which has the simulated wait for 10 minutes via ping as the first build step (Execute Windows batch command), in your case `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 600`, after which the rest build steps are executed; along with the post-build actions.

[edit 22.01.2017: changed the body of the ping command. initially it was pinging 1.1.1.1 which would result in ping Request timed out, potentially marking the Jenkins build as a failure, even though the wait period would be correct]